# Android MediaPlayer causing Not Responding error - Release not working as intended

Tags: android, resources, media-player, release, android-mediaplayer

I'm making an Android game-app in which you start as a little fish, and you need to eat smaller fish.
Each time you eat a smaller fish (by swimming against them), a sound plays. This is the code for playing the sound:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(GobbleFishGame.this, R.raw.bite);
                if (!mPlaySound) {
                    return;
                }
mp.start();
MPRelease();
```

This works well for the first few fishes. But after having eaten some fishes (the amount varies, but it's around 8-11 fishes), the game suddenly stops and I get the "Activity GobbleFish (in application GobbleFish) is not responding." error. I think it has something to do with too much resources being allocated to the MediaPlayer, therefore I've created a sub which releases mp's resources, and then creating a new MediaPlayer mp (this sub is called every time a fish is eaten). This is the code for the sub:

```
private void MPRelease(){
        MPReleaseCount += 1;
        if(MPReleaseCount==5){
            mp.release();
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            //mp = MediaPlayer.create(GobbleFishGame.this, R.raw.bite);

            //mp.reset();

            MPReleaseCount=0;
        }
    }
```

When MPReleaseCount is 5, mp gets released and recreated (so after 5 fishes are eaten).
I hoped that this would work, but it doesn't. I still have the problem that after some fishes are eaten (last time was 17 fishes, so MPRelease should have been called 3 times already), I get the "is not responding" error and I have to Force Close or Wait.

Can anyone tell me how I could do this to release the resources? Because I think that's the issue. I can't really tell if that's the issue because I don't get any error message in my LogCat in Eclipse. I did get this error report after Force Closing the app because of a "is not responding" error:

```
ANR in (my activity)
Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now I used another way (a handler) to play my music and sounds, and now I never get the "is not responding"-error. However, the problem is now that I can eat quite some fishes (amount still varies), but after an amount of fishes have been eaten, the sounds won't play. This doesn't affect my gameplay other than that the sound when eating a fish is gone. However, some time after the moment that the sound refused to play, the sound starts playing again as sudden as it stopped when I eat a fish. Why is this? I keep thinking that I have to release the MediaPlayer resources at some point...

Answer (score 1):

Don't release and create the MediaPlayer everytime you used it. Create it once with your audiosource and call a `seekTo(0)` in an `OnCompletionListener()`. Then play it again.

Also have a look at `SoundPool` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html which is made for usecases like yours where you have to play the same audio multiple times. It stores the audio and plays it on demand. You also have a lower audio latency than with MediaPLayer.